# I’m having trouble reproducing publish_actions.

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

I have one android application, i need to upload video on facebook fan page, so requested for publish_actions permission but every time i rejected and same result shawn by facebook team

[image]

can anyone help me to solve these issue ?

Comment: Have you created a test user and went through the steps that you tell the reviewer to do? Does it work?

Comment: No i haven't, i need to know what is this "Can you provide a timeline screenshot of the published story?"

Comment: Then start with doing what I said. That will verify that your steps works for the reviewer. And that message is just that you need to take a screenshot of the story

Comment: when i have to ask about "publish_actions" permission ? login time or just before upload video...

Comment: What it looks like on timeline

Comment: can you please share those steps or any reference url ?
what i did...
i have one story in open graph section and one test user account

Comment: how can i publish the story from within my app with a test user.

Comment: Just do what you put in the steps for the reviewer to do

Comment: Did you get permission? If yes, what was your reply.